# Request is blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, cors

I am running a C# Controller locally and it is serving endpoint `/api`. I have a local html page with Javascript trying to fetch data from that endpoint. But I see the console with this failure.

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44388/api' from origin 'null'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response
> serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
> resource with CORS disabled.

In my C# controller project, in the Startup.cs , I already setup this in         `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });
```

and in        `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`, I have put

```
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
```

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Thank you.

Update:
I tried update the code to do this. But I still get the same issue.

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
      builder =>
      {
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader();
      }));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this syntax

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                      builder =>
                       {
                       builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyHeader();
              }));

        .....
            
        }

        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .....

           // app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

         //  app.UseAuthorization();
         // app.UseEndpoints(..
 
         }
```

Make sure that UseCors should be in the end of Configure method but before UseAuthorizaton. AddCors should be at the top of Configure services.

Comment: Thanks @Serge. I tried your suggestion, but I am still getting the same error. I have update my code in my question.

Comment: @NJohnson You have to move app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin"); to place immediately after  UserRouting

Comment: Thanks @Serge. You help me resolve my issue.